# how to get back to original status/user after setuid()?

Tags: c, setuid

I have a program to run as root, and during execution this program will do a few things as different uers, so I wanted to use a serial of setuid()s. But, I found that, after setuid(user1), I become user1 and thus don't have the privilege to do setuid(user2).

How can I get back to root so that I can do setuid(user2)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fork`, let the child `setuid` and perform whatever actions that needs to be done as the second user. The root parent waits for the child and continues when the child has finished executing.

```
childpid = fork();
if (childpid < 0) {
    // fork failed
} 
if (childpid == 0) {
  // Child
  setuid(user1);
  prepareUser1();  // Do some stuff as user1.
  exit(0);         // Done as user1
} else {
  // parent: wait for child to finish
  waitpid(childpid);
}
// Parent continues as root...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, Read the man : [setuid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html)

But you can try to chmod your file then you will be able to call setuid(0) to come back as yout first uid

Answer (score 0):

The `setuid` says the following:

> a set-user-ID-root program wishing to temporarily drop root privileges, assume the identity of a non-root user, and then regain root privileges afterwards cannot use setuid(). You can
>          accomplish this with seteuid(2)

Meaning that you cannot use `setuid()` become root as you are unprivileged user. 
You have to use [seteuid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html) to become a root user.

Try this sample program to use [seteuid](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html) and change the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. By design, once you drop root privileges, you cannot get it back

[man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) page says:

> If the user is root or the program is set-user-ID-root, special care must be taken. The **setuid()** function checks the effective user ID of the caller and if it is the superuser, all process-related user ID's are set to uid. After this has occurred, it is impossible for the program to regain root privileges